# Matlab figures: thick (1pt) lines are thinned near the border.

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to make some simple line plots in Matlab with 1pt thickness lines (the default is 0.5pt I think). My eps/pdf output, created with export_fig, has two problems:

1) Look at the top of the y-axis. The tick mark and axis do not overlap properly. This also happens at the origin if there are no tick marks at zero (I mean the x and y axes don't fully overlap). If the axis lines were 0.5pt longer at each end, then there would be a nice corner.

2) The top of the plotted function is thinned near the topmost edge of the plot. This looks really bad to me. The does not happen if I have box('on') - the color functions just print over the top of the black boundary box. But I need the box gone for my final figures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Oh I can't post an image!? Please see my figure here: http://postimg.org/image/jq69yy747/ )

```
transfer_fig = figure; 

plot(w_ppm,f1,'LineWidth',1); hold on;
plot(w_ppm,f2,'LineWidth',1,'Color','r','LineStyle','--');


xlabel('\omega_S (ppm)','FontSize',8,'FontName','Arial');
ylabel('Transfer (%)','FontSize',8,'FontName','Arial');

set(gcf,'Position',[50 500 300 300/1.618]) % Set figure format
set(gca,'YTick',[0 50 100],...
    'XTick',[0  20  40 60],...
    'TickDir','out',...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'FontSize',8,...
    'FontName','Arial',...
    'Clipping','off',...
    'Color',[1 1 1]);

axis([w_ppm(1) w_ppm(end) 0 100]);
box('off');

export_fig transfer -eps -pdf -png -transparent -nocrop
```

Answer (score 1):

A cheap and quick fix might be to just plot out further

`axis([w_ppm(1) (w_ppm(end)+5) 0 105]);`

Comment: Thanks. Of course, it looks a bit silly to have an axis extending past 100, since in this case the units are %. I can set the y limit to e.g. 100.5 and it looks alright. This will have to be adjusted manually for each plot I guess.

Thanks